# How to add multiple ComboBoxItems to TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

My objective is to bind the SelectedItem.Text to a TextBox. However, there can be more than one selection, so if a user picks one choice from the ComboBox, they can select another choice. In which case, it would add the second choice to the first choice into a textbox.

```
private void txtTrnInter_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in cmbInter.Items)
    {
        txtTrnInter.Text += item.ToString();
    }
}
```

The output should be: "ComboBoxItem1" + "ComboBoxItem2" + "ComboBoxItem3" etc. to a TextBox.

Comment: SelectedItems property is not available to me. And like: <ComboBoxItem Content="Item1"

Comment: By multiple items I mean by clicking a cmbBox item, for it to be added to the TextBox. Then for them to click the cmbBox again, and select a new item.

Comment: Think about using a ListBox or similar if you need multiselection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void cmbInter_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string selectedItem = cmbInter.SelectedItem.ToString();
    txtTrnInter.Text += cmbInter.SelectedItem.ToString() + " ";
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbInter" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                  SelectionChanged="cmbInter_SelectionChanged">
    <s:String>a</s:String>
    <s:String>b</s:String>
    <s:String>c</s:String>
</ComboBox>

<TextBox x:Name="txtTrnInter" />
```

It will add the currently selected item to the `TextBox` for each selection in the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Perfect. My issue was it kept returning Systems.Windows.Form.ComboBox.SelectedItem.Item1 instead of the string. Thanks!